# How do I load a bmp into a ContentPresenter?

Tags: c#, wpf, bmp, contentpresenter

I have a ContentPresenter Content and I have just loaded a bmp from file. I would like the bmp to appear in the ContentPresenter and take advantage of the zoom features.

The code that I have (which only displays the path of the bmp file) is:

```
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(selectedFileName);
        bitmap.EndInit();
        Content = bitmap;
```

Comment: `Content.Content = bitmap`?

Comment: Why not directly use an Image class ?

Comment: I don't know enought about Image classes to think that was the correct answer. I'm just trying to put together the front end as quickly as possible on this project, because the real work is writing the underlying AI code; note the UI (which will be thrown out later anyway). Would using an Image class solve all my problems?

Comment: This seems to have solved it:   contentPresenter.Content = bitmap;

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to preload the image, you would have to create a dependancy property on Main Window. You would also have to use [WPF Pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx). The XAML and codebehind files are given below:

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPFApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPFApp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="725">

    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
            <Label Content="Select Image" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="10,10,100,10"></Label>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cbImageSelect" Height="20" Width="400" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Width="250" Height="250" Grid.Row="1" >
            <ContentPresenter.Content>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Width="220" Height="220">
                </Image>
            </ContentPresenter.Content>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

XAML.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestWPFApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            cbImageSelect.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "test1.bmp", "test2.bmp" };
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageUriProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageUri", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow));

        public string ImageUri
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ImageUriProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageUriProperty, value); }
        }

        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageUri = "pack://application:,,,/" + ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as string);
        }
    }
}
```

Location of Images: test1.bmp and test2.bmp

[image]

Properties of test1.bmp and test2.bmp
[image]
[image]

Comment: This method works great! Except I want to be able to load the bmp file at runtime from a dialog box from a menuitem. How would I do this? I don't want to be tied to a pre-loaded bmp.

Comment: @zetar : I have updated my answer to reflect run time loading of images depending on combo-box selection. Hopefully you can make appropriate changes for menuitem and dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

A `ContentPresenter` basically does two things: display an element directly, or display data in a way defined by a `DataTemplate` (more detail in the remarks on [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx)). `BitmapImage` is not an element, and doesn't have a specific DataTemplate associated with it, so the ContentPresenter falls back to simply displaying the `ToString` of it.

You can either create an `Image` element and set the content directly to it, or define a DataTemplate either by `ContentTemplate` or as a resource with a `DataType`.

ContentTemplate:

```
<ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Resource:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type BitmapImage}">
        <Image Source="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: This works great... except I've lost my zoom and scroll abilities. The example code that I was working from is here: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97871/WPF-simple-zoom-and-drag-support-in-a-ScrollViewer). I really appreciate this help; thanks!